# Mongo saving ISODate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Im currently saving the next date into a collection

> 2022-01-02T00:00:00-05:00

But somehow when I check the date in the db looks like this (adding 16 seconds)

> 2022-01-02T05:00:16.000+00:00

When It should be saved like this

> 2022-01-02T05:00:00.000+00:00

Someone know why is this happening?

EDIT: I found out that after I convert excel to json the 16 seconds are being added, this is how I convert excel to json with the package "convert-excel-to-json
"

```
const convertExcel = async (path) => {
    const result = excelToJson({
        sourceFile: path,
        sheets: [
            {
                name: "Sheet1",
                header: {
                    rows: 1,
                },
                columnToKey: {
                    A: "DATE",
                },
            },
        ],
    });
    Collection.insertMany(result.Sheet1);
};
```

Im getting the date like this:

```
{
    DATE: 2022-01-02T05:00:16.000Z,
}
```

Excel:
[image: Excel]

Comment: I doubt it's mongo behavior, I vote it's logic on your side

Comment: Why logic by my side if I just pasted the date on the object

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Seems to be a know problem: https://github.com/DiegoZoracKy/convert-excel-to-json/issues/33

Comment: Maybe related to [Differences between the 1900 and the 1904 date system in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system)